# how to register Plone view for a particular HTTP method type

Tags: python, plone

I would like to be able to register Views in Plone only for a particular HTTP method type, eg. for POST only, or only for particular `Accept:` header submitted by client.

I know it is not really possible to configure a View that way using regular ZCML configuration directives.

Are there other mechanisms that could be utilized for this purpose, short of writing a proxy view that delegates the request to other views per HTTP method and so on?

Comment: I would love to get this feature into plone/zope....

Comment: @vangheem might be possible already with `plone.rest` (https://github.com/plone/plone.rest/blob/master/src/plone/rest/events.py), but registering different views for one end point to a specific layer (i.e. `layer="IPOST"` for the correct one and a default view for unsupported request for proper error message) is rather clumsy.

Comment: So first adding interfaces to the request from within a IBeforeTraverseEvent subscriber and then registering views against those interfaces would do the trick?

Comment: Makes me think it would be a nice if ZCA supported registering stuff against tagged values of interfaces...

Answer (score 4):

For the "post only" protection you can also use the inner features of [plone.protect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.protect):

```
@protect(PostOnly)
...
```

While for the `accept` header I fear you must inspect the request data manually.

Answer (score 3):

Typically most views follow the update/render pattern, and generally it makes sense to put that in the update method, a common location to do permission/access/data integrity checks like other various libraries.  A complete demonstration follows:

```
from AccessControl import Unauthorized
from zope.publisher.browser import BrowserPage

class PostOnlyPage(BrowserPage):

    def update(self):
        if not self.request.method == 'POST':
            raise Unauthorized

    def render(self):
        return 'A POST only render'

    def __call__(self):
        self.update()
        return self.render()
```

If you are doing this to make existing libraries (such as `z3c.form`) to enforce access methods you can consider doing something like:

```
class StrictPostForm(z3c.form.form.PostForm):
    def update(self):
        if not self.request.method == 'POST':
            raise Unauthorized
        super(StrictPostForm, self).update()
```